# Get HDD size programatically on MacOS using C++

Tags: macos, c++11, filesystems

I am building an application and I need to get the HDD size:
I am working on Mac OS. I have tried this:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>

float MonitoringWorker::getHDDSize()
{
 struct statfs statf;

 statfs(".", &statf);

 std::cout << "statf.f_bsize = " << statf.f_bsize << std::endl;
 std::cout << "statf.f_blocks = " << statf.f_blocks << std::endl;
 std::cout << "statf.f_bavail = " << statf.f_bavail << std::endl;
 std::cout << "statf.f_bfree = "<< statf.f_bfree << std::endl;
 std::cout << "GB = "<< ((statf.f_bsize * statf.f_blocks) /  kBytesInGB)<< std::endl;
 return 0;

}
```

I am seeing that the result in GB is 465. However checking System Information tells me that I have 500GB
What am I doing wrong? Is this best way to get those numbers?

Note: I am using C++ on Mac OS, can't use Objective-C

Thanks in advance

Comment: The program gets the file system capacity, not the physical capacity of the HDD.

Comment: how can I get the physical capacity, then?